# why a .net 1.1 code gets compiled in 2.0 and throws an error?

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have web projects build in VS2003/1.1 framework and deployed in a webserver with IIS setting specified to 1.1 framework.lets say project X

I also have another web project which is build with VS2008/2.0. IIS setting - ASP version 2.0 is selected and all pages are assigned to run with 2.0* dlls. Lets say project Y

Now the problem seem to be when I hit project x, sometimes it throws errors like:

```
error BC30456: 'Initialize Culture' is not a member of ASP
```

During troubleshooting this issue, I browsed through 2.0 Temporary ASP.Net files `"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\"` and found temp files generated for project X. (HUH?)

How/why 1.1 project gets compiled in 2.0 only when it errors out.( or we could put it this way that it errors out every time it gets compiled in 2.0 which it is not supposed to)

I'm confused as to why this is happening when project X has nothing to do with .net 2.0.

Adding this info:

IIS version 6.0

I forgot to mention that project X works 95 percent of the time without any errors under 1.1. This error throws randomly which we could not recreate. The time the project error out is at the same time it gets compiled with 2.0

Comment: One other thing that I have seen happen as well, do the apps both use the Cache object? Cache.Insert, Cache.Add, Cache.Remove? I have seen instances (usually under heavy load) where this has corrupted one app or the other, and caused all manner of problems. Its rare, I have only seen it on two servers, both were deployed in india and running W2K3 Server Standard.

Comment: You still miss something critical. What's the relationship between the two projects? If one of them is under the other as a virtual directory, that so called side by side execution can still lead to problems (even if you use separate application pools. Why not fully migrate the 1.1 project to 2.0? You just need an experienced ASP.NET developer.

Answer (score 2):

Are the two projects sharing the same AppPool on the IIS server? You need to have separate app pools for 1.1 and 2.0 processes running on the same IIS server.

Comment: Thanks Gray - But I have separate AppPools. One for 1.1 projects and one for 2.0 projects.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a .NET version, if you have IIS installed and are running ASP.NET, then the aspnet_regiis tool is run. This sets IIS to use the .NET version that you're installing.

The exact same thing happened to me about seven years ago. I installed a .NET 2.0 Windows Forms application on a production server, and immediately saw errors.

The solution is to run the .NET 1.1 version of aspnet_regiis.

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing that when I first encountered the error.But that didn't fix it.

I forgot to mention that project X works 95 percent of the time without any errors under 1.1. This error throws randomly which we could not recreate. 

The time the project error out is at the same time it gets compiled with 2.0.

Comment: Please update your question with that information. It will be helpful to others who try to help you.